# Django: Instantiating a form in a custom class based view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

This is my first post, and I am new to Django so go easy on me!

I am trying to convert my function based views into class based views so I can reuse the views easily in other apps, and am struggling with instantiating a form inside the class.

I have the following function based view:

```
def object_create(request):

    def get_date():
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        enquiry_date = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        return enquiry_date

    initial_dict = {
            "account_handler" : request.user,
            "prep_location" : request.user.profile.location,
            "load_location":   request.user.profile.location,
            "return_location": request.user.profile.location,
            "status":"Enquiry",
            "enquiry_date": get_date()
        }
    
    object_form = QuoteForm(request.POST or None, initial = initial_dict)

    context = {
            'form': object_form,
        }

    if request.method == 'GET':

        return render(request, "rental_quotes/form.html", context )

        # If we are saving the form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        if object_form.is_valid():
            new_object = object_form.save()
            context = {
                'object': new_object
            }
            found_count = Quote.objects.all().count()
            request.session['rental_quotes_current_index'] = (found_count-1)
            request.session['rental_quotes_found_count'] = found_count
            new_page = json.dumps({
            'url': reverse("rental_quotes-detail", args=[new_object.id]),
            'index': found_count-1,
            'found_count': found_count,
            'content': render_to_string('rental_quotes/pages/detail.html', context)
            })
        
            return JsonResponse(new_page, safe=False, status=200)

        else:
            return render(request, 'rental_quotes/form_block.html', context )
```

Which works fine.

In my attempt at creating a class I can import into a class based view I have:

```
class ObjectCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
        
    def get_date():
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        enquiry_date = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        return enquiry_date

    def get (self, request):

        object_form = self.request.form(request.POST or None, initial = self.initial_dict)

        context = {
            'form': object_form,
        }
        
        return render(request, f'{self.app_name}/form.html', context )

    def post (self, request):
        
        object_form = self.form(request.POST or None, initial = self.initial_dict)

        if self.object_form.is_valid():
            new_object = object_form.save()
            context = {
                'object': new_object
            }
            found_count = self.model.objects.all().count()
            request.session[f'{self.app_name}_current_index'] = (found_count-1)
            request.session[f'{self.app_name}_found_count'] = found_count
            new_page = json.dumps({
            'url': reverse(f'{self.app_name}-detail', args=[new_object.id]),
            'index': found_count-1,
            'found_count': found_count,
            'content': render_to_string(f'{self.app_name}/pages/detail.html', context)
            })
        
            return JsonResponse(new_page, safe=False, status=200)

        else:
            return render(request, f'{self.app_name}/form_block.html', context )
```

And in my views.py I have (which inherits from the class above):

```
class ObjectCreateView(ObjectCreate):

    app_name = 'rental_quotes'
    form = QuoteForm
```

The problem is, when I load that view, I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /rental_quotes/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/simon/Desktop/JEDI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/simon/Desktop/JEDI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/simon/Desktop/JEDI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/simon/Desktop/JEDI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 71, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/simon/Desktop/JEDI/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/simon/Desktop/JEDI/JEDI/framework/views.py", line 109, in get
    object_form = self.form(request.POST or None)
AttributeError: 'ObjectCreate' object has no attribute 'form'
```

My goal here is to have classes which define custom views that I just need to set attributes such as models and forms, so I can easily re-use the views in other apps by just changing attributes such as model and form.

Comment: Please take a look into Class Based Views. It looks like you're implementing CreateView yourself. It can be a bit complex in the beginning, but I suggest this resource for learning Django class based views: http://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am trying to implement my own version of CreateView, and I have tried using the generic but couldn't see how I could customise it to the level of detail I required. It looked like I could only return a template, whereas I want to set some session variables and if the form is valid return a Json response. For other views I have several formsets too so I thought it would be better to create my own.

Comment: It may be the case that the standardization that Django uses is not suitable for your use cases. Perhaps fastAPI or Flask will be less restrictive in this regard?